Embedding f.g. groups in 2-generated groups
Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. Can $G$ be embedded as a finite-index subgroup of a 2-generated group? 100-generated?
I strongly doubt it but I don't know a counterexample.

For 2-generated embeddings, a counter-example is the (2,3,7)-Coxeter group. For 100, I think you should take a direct product of 101 pairwise nonisomorphic triangle Coxeter groups.

@MoisheKohan Interesting, thanks! Does this also rule out quasi-isometry with a 2-gen group?

I am unsure how to prove a qi version, but I know how to prove a "virtually isomorphic" ("commensurable") version. It is a bit more complicated variation on the direct product argument.

It may be too restrictive a case to be useful, but any group of Euler characteristic $-1$, e.g. a 3-generator 1-relator group, cannot be embedded with finite index as a proper subgroup of any torsion-free group.

A relevant example could be the free product $G_n:= \mathbb{Z}^2 \ast \mathbb{Z}^3 \ast \cdots \ast \mathbb{Z}^n$. A group $H$ quasi-isometric to $G_n$ decomposes as a graph of groups whose edge-groups are finite and whose vertex-groups are virtually $\mathbb{Z}^k$ for $2 \leq k \leq n$ (at least one factor for each $k$). A naive guess is that, for $n >> m$, $H$ is not $m$-generated. But there is something to prove here.

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$Let $G_1,...,G_m$ be pairwise non-isomorphic maximal lattices in isometry groups of real-hyperbolic spaces $\mathbb H^{k_i}$
(possibly of different dimensions $k_i\ge 3$) with nontrivial abelianizations. (Note that every lattice is contained in a maximal lattice as a finite index subgroup.) For instance, we can take some pairwise noncommensurable arithmetic subgroups of the simplest type which do not preserve orientation: All such lattices have nontrivial homomorphisms to $\mathbb Z_2$. Take
$$
G=G_1\times ... \times G_m.
$$
Suppose that we have an inclusion $G\to H$ as a finite index subgroup. Then, by Mostow Rigidity, the group  $H$ acts isometrically (possibly, with finite kernel) on the product of hyperbolic spaces
$$
X=\mathbb H^{k_1}\times ... \times \mathbb H^{k_m}
$$
extending the product action of $G$. In view of maximality of each $G_i$ (and the assumption that these groups are pairwise nonisomorphic), this action of $H$ cannot permute the factors and, thus, again, by maximality, the action has to be equal to the action of $G_i$ on the corresponding factor in the product. Thus, $H$ is an extension of $G$ by a finite subgroup $K$, the kernel of the action of $H$ on $X$. The group $G$ and, hence, $H$, has a surjective homomorphism to a product of $m$ nontrivial abelian groups (abelianizations of the groups $G_i$). Thus, the rank of $H$ (the minimal number of generators) is at least $m$. The same argument works when we allow some $k_i=2$ as long as the corresponding group $G_i$ is a triangle reflection group.

When you say "by Mostow rigidity": I know this as a consequence of QI rigidity (it is explicitly stated in one of the Kleiner-Leeb papers), but do not see immediately why it follows from Mostow rigidity.

@YCor: Kleiner-Leeb would be an overkill, I use the fact that the automorphism group of a lattice is a bigger lattice, which follows from Mostow (one first passes to a finite index subgroup in $G_i$ to ensure normality).

Thanks, I see. So QI rigidity allows to encompass $k_i=2$.

I suspect the dimension-two case only needs Nielsen realisation.

Here is a counterexample, coming from the theory of hyperbolic 2-orbifold groups.
Consider the fundamental group $\pi_1(S_2)$ of a closed, oriented surface of genus $2$ (its minimum number of generators is $4$).
Consider a group embedding $\pi_1(S_2) \hookrightarrow \Gamma$ whose image has finite index. There's a theorem saying that $\Gamma$ has a finite normal subgroup $N$ whose quotient group $\Gamma/N$, like $\pi_1(S_2)$, is the fundamental group of some closed hyperbolic $2$-orbifold. Since $\pi_1(S_2)$ is torsion free, it follows that the composition $\pi_1(S_2) \mapsto \Gamma \mapsto \Gamma/N$ is an embedding, and the image of this embedding clearly has finite index.
But from the classification of closed hyperbolic 2-orbifolds, none of their fundamental groups is 2-generated.

No, plenty are 2-generated (van Dyck groups).

I think $\pi_1(S_2)$ admits a finite-order automorphism that's transitive on a generating set (right?), which seems like a recipe for embedding with finite index in a 2-generated group.

But if you take, say, the reflection group $(2,3,7)$, it will be maximal NEC group and, hence, cannot embed in a 2-generated group.

@MattZaremsky: Yes, fundamental groups of all compact orientable surfaces embed as finite index subgroups in 2-generated groups.

Ah, shoot, I mis-thought this. I thought about the triangle groups but not the van Dyck groups.

@MoisheKohan How do you prove that the 237 reflection group is not 2-generated?

(From the abelianization, the 246 reflection group is not generated by less than 3 elements; if it's maximal, we're done.)

@MoisheKohan The 237 Coxeter grou is 2-generated (see theorem  A) https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1005032526329.pdf
